# Installing Drip script code snippet to Wix website

Tags: javascript, velo

Trying to install a drip `script` tag to my wix website, to no avail.

Wix has just released `developer tools` in beta and I'm currently playing around with it. Able to access the site code (very minimal) - I'm sure there is a way to add this snippet script to Wix through the function Wix provides below.

Asking me to add the code right before the `</body>` closing tag, but I'm unable to see it inside Wix.

Here's what I have but it's not working

```
$w.onReady(function () {
    //TODO: write your page related code here...

  <!-- Drip -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var .....;
    </script>
  <!-- end Drip -->

});
```

The code will allow me to track website visits on [Drip](https://www.drip.com/) - provided by Drip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `$w` selector you may control components on your site but not manipulate the HTML directly (like in `jQuery` for example).

If you're trying to use a 3rd party library, I think Wix Code is about to launch that option soon so you may check on [Wix Code Coming Features](https://www.wix.com/code/home/coming-soon) from time to time.

Anyway, regarding user visit tracking, Wix has a built in Analytics options in you site's management dashboard so you may save this extra load on your site